# Deleting file (including content cleaning)

Tags: android, linux, file, file-io, filesystems

In my application I need to delete file with sensitive information. For that I'm writing to file some garbage generated by random bytes and then deleting using File.delete() method, like here:

```
long size=file.length();
Random r=new SecureRandom();
OutputStream os=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
while(size > 0)
{
    os.write(r.nextInt());
    size--;
}
os.close();
file.delete();
```

So the question is: does this method guarantee that if someone will undelete file one will find only garbage instead of real content? I'm not completely sure that writing to file would guarantee that the same sectors in underline Linux filesystem will be overwritten... Please give a hint - what to do - to be sure that file content is destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't guarantee that. The reason for that is the filesystem implementation underneath - it is not forced by any standards to ever *overwrite* existing data. A fully valid, (POSIX-)standard-conforming way of implementing a write operation for a filesystem is to allocate a brand new block of storage, put your "new" data into there, and then change the block structure of the file in such a way that the new data block is referenced for the location you write in the file and the previously-used data block is "released" - whatever that means in detail. After that, you can't access the old data anymore (through the filesystem) but it's still on disk, so save erasing the entire storage medium you're not erasing the traces.

Many filesystem implementations of functionality like snapshots or replication rely on this mechanism (Copy-On-Write). Linux Btrfs or Solaris ZFS use it extensively. I think Android's YAFFS does too. As Chris mentioned, the wear leveling FTL in any flash memory will behave like that as well.

The answer that's usually given how to deal with this problem on filesytems employing copy-on-write is to never have it occur in the first place. I.e. encrypt the file when writing it, and "throw away the key" when deleting the file. What you can't decrypt you can't recover ... but I agree there's the chicken-egg problem of where/how to store the encryption key.

Comment: Thanx for very comprehensive answer. I need to think how to deal with this information

Comment: Is it possible to know exact ids of blocks occupied by a given file? And then overwrite those blocks?

Comment: Not for all filesystems. On those where you can, you also, normally, overwrite existing data, and your method would do what you want. It's just not guaranteed that it'll happen that way. Also, on btrfs or ZFS, for example, if you _would_ overwrite the existing blocks the filesystem would _detect_ that (because a block checksum stored _elsewhere_ will show the filesystem that the file's blocks don't contain what they should) and you'd get errors attempting any further operation on the file. They might even undo (!) your overwrites from cached data ...

Comment: If you absolutely require this functionality, you'll have to have control about what filesystem type runs on your device, and then actually modify the filesystem kernel driver code itself to perform this "overwrite" when freeing blocks. But - even if you go that far, power loss when a block is just freed (and inaccessible through the filesystem) but not yet filled with random data means you'll have "ghosts of the past" on the device. Cryptography is the better solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not guarantee that the original blocks are overwritten - on a flash device it's extremely unlikely that they would be, though one might need tools below the O/S level or even below the chip data sheet interface level to do the recovery.

You really cannot guarantee erasure except if you have flash memory with no on-board controller that can substitute blocks and repeatedly erase and overwrite it from its low level driver, or you physically destroy the media.

If you are talking about the SDcard with a fat filesystem, I believe based on past recovery of an accidentally saved back picture edit that linux doesn't even try to write back to the same blocks of the file system.

You can confirm that the data is still recoverable by putting the card in a linux box and grepping the raw device file for something known to be in the deleted file; unfortunately this will not prove that the data might not still be there in a block that's been re-mapped by the device driver or an on-chip controller, and potential accessible by a lower-level tool.

Comment: I was talking about SD card with FAT system. So the only option would be to clean all available free blocks?

Comment: Against an unsophisticated attacker, over writing the entire device file on which the filesystem is built (from a desktop linux, android won't let you) might work.  But it's not secure against more sophisticated attackers as SD cards have an internal controller which remaps blocks for wear leveling and error issues, and you can't rule out the existence of a card vendor recovery tool which can pierce that remapping.  If it's important, your only real option is to physically destroy the SD card.